# write nsdata in a file at a specific position

Tags: ios, file-io, nsdata, writetofile

I have the following code for writing data in a file:

```
NSData *chunk=...; //some data
 NSArray *docDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [docDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName   = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestFile.txt"];
 [chunk writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];
```

If I know the size of the file (let;s say 10*chunk) and if i also receive the position of each chunk in the total length of the file, how can I add write data to file at that specific position?

Comment: Do you want to write at the end of the file?
If not, do you want to insert the new data and move the data after the insertion point to the end of the file?
Or, do you want to replace the data at the point of insertion with the new data?

Comment: I want to insert the new data and move the data after the insertion point. I could also encounter the cae where i have to add data at the end of the file. So this two cases can occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your questions, your best bet is to use [NSOutputStream](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it makes operations like these easier to handle.

That being said, you would append to the end of the file like this:

```
NSOutputStream *stream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:filePath append:YES];
[stream open];
NSData *chunk = ...; // some data
[stream write:(uint8_t *)[chunk bytes] maxLength:[chunk length]];
[stream close];
// remember to always handle memory (if not using ARC) //
```

To insert a chunk of data in the middle of a file is somewhat more involved:

```
NSData *chunk = ...; // some data
NSString *filePath = ... ; // get the file //
NSUInteger insertionPoint = ...; // get the insertion point //
// make sure the file exists, if it does, do the following //
NSData *oldData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
// error checking would be nice... if (oldData) ... blah //
NSOutputStream *stream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];
[stream open];
[stream write:(uint8_t *)[oldData bytes] maxLength:insertionPoint]; // write the old data up to the insertion point //
[stream write:(uint8_t *)[chunk bytes] maxLength:[chunk length]]; // write the new data //
[stream write:(uint8_t *)&[oldData bytes][insertionPoint] maxLength:[oldData length] - insertionPoint]; // write the rest of old data at the end of the file //
[stream close];
// remember to always handle memory (if not using ARC) //
```

Disclaimer: Code written in browser.

Comment: What's the advantage of `NSOutputStream` over `NSFileHandle`?

Comment: The only real advantage here is the ability to specify how much data to write each operation, as opposed to `NSFileHandle` that writes entire `NSData` objects to the file. If the only operations you are going to perform on the file are writing operations I believe `NSOutputStream` is the more straight forward solution; but `NSFileHandle` is the obvious winner for flexibility, if you want to perform more complex operations that is.

Comment: Thank you! Is it important the lenght of the file when creating it?

Comment: the insertionPoint is the insertPoint? At the last line up above [stream close] i have an error message: Operand of type çonst void'where arithmetic or pointer type is required

Comment: yes, sorry about the typo, I edited the answer to rename the variable from `insertPoint` to `insertionPoint` and added an `&` to get the right address from the data array.

Comment: The `&[oldData bytes][insertionPoint]` part could also be written as `[oldData bytes] + insertionPoint` if you prefer that syntax.